ComposePanel as JList item keeps recomposing in Compose for Desktop
In a Compose/Swing interop project I have a SwingPanel added with a JList that uses a renderer which renders a ComposePanel. But when I launch the app, I find content of ComposePanels in JList keeps recomposing, but I can't tell what's triggering it. I simplified my code below:
val fakeData = mutableListOf<String>().apply {
    repeat(5) {
        add("test $it")
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 80.dp, bottom = 20.dp)
            ) {
                Text("Recompose Test")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

                SwingPanel(
                    background = Color.Red,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(500.dp),
                    factory = {
                        JPanel().apply {
                            layout = BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)
                            alignmentY = Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT

                            val composeJList = JList(fakeData.toTypedArray()).apply {
                                cellRenderer = ComposeRenderer()
                            }

                            val scrollPane = JScrollPane(composeJList)
                            add(scrollPane)

                            isVisible = true
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}

And the ListCellRenderer:
class ComposeRenderer : JPanel(), ListCellRenderer<String> {
    private val composePanel = ComposePanel()

    init {
        layout = BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)
        add(composePanel)
    }

    override fun getListCellRendererComponent(
        list: JList<out String>,
        text: String,
        index: Int,
        isSelected: Boolean,
        cellHasFocus: Boolean
    ): Component {
        print("recompose")
        composePanel.setContent {
            Text(text)
        }
        return this
    }
}

Run the following code and you will see "recompose" flushes console output. Can anyone help me with this problem, is it a bug, or where I did wrong?
